# Call stored procedure with user-defined table type as parameter; error: column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have tried several ways to make this work but getting the same error when `ExecuteReader` is called:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Looks like the table type column names are not getting mapped with datatable column name but not sure why. Following is the .net and SQL code which has worked for other people who have written blogs and made videos where I got this code from but unfortunately does not work for me. Please reply if you see anything wrong or I have missed anything.

Thank you.

.Net code:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DataColumnName",typeof(string)));
       
foreach(var item in request.ControlValues)
{
    var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
    dataRow["DataColumnName"] = item.DataColumnName;                        
    dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData]", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter cob = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cob", request.Cob);
cob.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
cob.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

SqlParameter function = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@function", request.Function);
function.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
function.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

SqlParameter searchColumnName = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchColumnName", Helper.GetControlSearchColumnName(request.SearchType));
searchColumnName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
searchColumnName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

SqlParameter controlValues = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlValues", dt);
controlValues.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
controlValues.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
controlValues.TypeName = "[dbo].[ControlValuesTable]";

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

SQL Server / stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData]
    @cob nvarchar(50),
    @function nvarchar(50),
    @searchColumnName nvarchar(50),
    @controlValues as [dbo].[ControlValuesTable] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
END
```

User-defined table type :

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ControlValuesTable AS 
    TABLE
    (
        DataColumnName varchar(100) 
    );
GO
```

Comment: Avoid using [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Are you *sure* that is your whole procedure? Aside: You should dispose your connection, command and reader with `using` blocks. Parameters are `NVarChar` in your case, you should declare them as such, also specify the `nvarchar` length. You can write the parameter code much shorter `cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Helper.GetControlSearchColumnName(request.SearchType)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code (changed so it can run stand alone):

```
        string ConnectionString = "cs"; // set your connection string here

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DataColumnName", typeof(string)));

        var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        dataRow["DataColumnName"] = "col1";
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter cob = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cob", "aa");
            cob.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            cob.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter function = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@function", "bb");
            function.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            function.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter searchColumnName = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchColumnName", "cc");
            searchColumnName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            searchColumnName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            SqlParameter controlValues = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@controlValues", dt);
            controlValues.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            controlValues.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            controlValues.TypeName = "[dbo].[ControlValuesTable]";

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

I also added a line to the body of your stored proc, as the stored proc you posted will give an error like:

> Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

without it.

```
drop proc [dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData]
GO
drop type dbo.ControlValuesTable
GO
CREATE TYPE dbo.ControlValuesTable AS 
    TABLE
    (
        DataColumnName varchar(100) 
    );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData]
    @cob nvarchar(50),
    @function nvarchar(50),
    @searchColumnName nvarchar(50),
    @controlValues as [dbo].[ControlValuesTable] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 select * from @controlValues
END
GO
```

This ran ok on my system.
If you still can't get it to work, perform an sql profiler trace to capture the raw sql request being sent to Sqlserver, and try replaying the request in SSMS.
e.g. the request trace should look something like:

```
declare @p4 dbo.ControlValuesTable
insert into @p4 values(N'col1')

exec [dbo].[GetQuoteSearchData] @cob='aa',@function='bb',@searchColumnName='cc',@controlValues=@p4
```

which when replayed in SSMS returns a row.

As a side note, I think you should also be able to remove this line:

```
controlValues.TypeName = "[dbo].[ControlValuesTable]";
```

as it's not required when CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer which helped me dig deeper and found out the problem was within Stored procedure. (y)